# create an empty list to fill it up with lists in R

Tags: r

I want to create an empty list so I can replace its elements with other lists.

For example

```
simulations = 10
seeds = sample(10000:99999, simulations, replace=F)

test_function <- function(seedX){
  lista = list(seedX=seedX, 
               dataframe=data.frame(x=runif(10, -5.0, 5.0),y=rnorm(10,mean = 0,sd = 1)))
  return(lista)
}
results <- vector("list", simulations) 
results[1] = test_function(seedX = seeds[1])
```

I get the following error:

```
Warning message:
In results[1] = test_function(seedX = seeds[1]) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just change

```
results[1] = test_function(seedX = seeds[1])
```

to

```
results[[1]] <- test_function(seedX = seeds[1])
```

The important change is the `[...]` element indexing operator to the `[[...]]` list component indexing operator, as you need to assign the list component to the new list. See https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.html.

(You should also use the `<-` assignment operator instead of `=`, mainly to follow the R convention, but also because `=` means something different (and therefore can't be used for assignments) in other contexts, such as named parameter specifications in function calls, so using `<-` allows for more consistency.)